# View returns error for certain ids in laravel

Tags: laravel, dynamic, model, controller, laravel-blade

This is really weird to me. when I want to display data from rows, some data return error.
I can only view data with `id`s `(1-7, 10, 13-17,22 and so)`, data with `id` `(8,9,11,12,18,19,20,21..)` return error.

if i go to `http://manajemenpasien.com/PasienPoli/17`, i get the page i expected. but when going to this `http://manajemenpasien.com/PasienPoli/19`, i get this error:

```
ErrorException in Collection.php line 1564:
Property [nama] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: D:\myProjects\manajemenPasien\resources\views\PasienPoli\show.blade.php)
```

`[nama]` is a field name in table `pasiens`

this is what I have in `PasienPoliController`:

```
public function show($id)
{
   $pasienpoli = PasienPoli::find($id);
   $pasien = Pasien::find($id)->PasienPoli;

   return view('pasienpoli.show', compact('pasienpoli','pasien'));  
   }
```

PasienPoli `Model`:

```
public function pasien()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Pasien');
}
```

Pasien `Model`:

```
public function pasienpoli()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\PasienPoli');
}
```

`show.blade.php`:

```
<h2>{{$pasienpoli->pasien->nama}}</h2>
```

Table structure of `pasien_polis`:

```
id - int(10) - auto_increment
polyclinic_id - int(11)
pasien_id - int(11)
penyakit - varchar(50)
```

Table structure of `pasiens`:

```
id - int(10) - auto_increment
nama - varchar(50)
```

what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely those ids do not exist in your database. Check your databse or dd the collection in your view to find out what's going on.

Comment: I have checked them, all exist.

Comment: dd($pasienpoli) to see what data you have got

Comment: dd with `id`=10 i get the data, dd with `id`=19, it says null.

Comment: sorry `id`=19 is empty, `id`=9 shows results in die dump. but error when `dd()` is removed while `id=10 displays data.

Comment: How about $pasienpoli = PasienPoli::all();dd($pasienpoli); in your controller

Comment: result gave me an array exactly the same as the data in the database. but this weird error still occurs in show page.

Comment: Anyway, this is probably just a little debugging for you to do rather than a helpful question. Happy debugging :)

Comment: I found the problem. there's a hidden field form in show page with this value `{{$pasien->nama}}` solved when i replace with `{{$pasienpoli->pasien->nama}}`. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: Aha! My next move is to google translate pasienpoli to find out what the hell this all about

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148079/discussion-between-kemika-and-daddi-al-amoudi).

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code to this:

```
public function show($id)
{
   if(($pasienpoli = PasienPoli::find($id)) == NULL)
   return view('pasienpoli.notfound', []);  
   $pasien = Pasien::find($id)->PasienPoli;

   return view('pasienpoli.show', compact('pasienpoli','pasien'));  
}
```

if the id does not exists you can return another view or what you want.

Comment: I found the problem. there's a hidden form field in show page with this value `{{$pasien->nama}}` solved when i replaced it with `{{$pasienpoli->pasien->nama}}`. Thanks for your time anyway.